# Can someone give me a step by step tutorial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codemirror, codemirror-modes

I started to use codeMirror... But i don't really understand the manual and don't find a good tutorial on the internet. At the moment, i managed to get this:

```
var codeHtml = $(".codemirror-html") [0];
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(codeHtml, {
    mode:  "htmlmixed",
    lineNumbers: true
});
```

It does basically works, there are linenumbers and a textarea :D, but the mode doesnt' works. It's just raw black text in the textarea. 
I think I importet the needed Files:

```
<script src="cm/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cm/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="cm/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="cm/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.. I alsow tried to add a theme, didn't worked as well.
Please, can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that reproduces problem. Should be able to get the necessary codemirror files from a cdn resource to put demo together in a sandbox like plunker or jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charliertfl the special thing ist, that it doesnt throw an error.. and the value : "string" doesnt works too... But why does the lineNumbers thing works ??? I'm getting crazy

Comment: no idea without seeing a demo . See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Or do you have any good tutorial for me ? because i think i don't understand the hole system of codeMirror.

Comment: Step by step tutorials are off topic as too broad, as are recommendations for off site resources

Answer (score -1):

The `htmlmixed` mode depends on the `xml` and `css` modes as well, so you'll have to add script tags for those.